# How do I know if my display glitching badly after an Ubuntu 22.04 system update is a device problem or an Ubuntu problem?

Tags: 22.04, login, display, lenovo, update-manager

I got a new Lenovo ThinkPad laptop 3 months ago on DOS version. I installed Ubuntu 22.04 as soon as I got it and it had been working smoothly since then. Today, I got a notification for a system update from the Ubuntu software update app. I clicked Install now and the prompt asked me to restart the device to install the new software. Since then, the device boots upto the login page, which appears black with only the cursor visible. Apparently this was a common problem, and many solutions on previous askubuntu posts referred to pressing Ctrl+Alt+F(1/2/3/4/5/6) to start the terminal login. None of these worked for my device, and at last I pressed enter on the login page and entered my password anyway (the screen was still black with only the cursor visible). Then my Ubuntu homepage appeared at last, but the display is glitching really badly (unusable). I tried inserting a USB stick with ubuntu 22.04 installed to try and see if I could reinstall ubuntu on my device, but the laptop keeps starting in the same way, leading to the black login page (the Bootable USB stick is not recognized on startup).

Now, my laptop is well within the warranty period, so if it's a Lenovo device display problem I can easily get it fixed. The problem is, my local authorized Lenovo service center says they don't have the training required to inspect Lenovo devices with Linus installed in them (they only work with windows). I need to know first if this is an Ubuntu OS problem (in which case, would someone kindly help me out) or a device problem before taking it to them. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

To know whether it is a problem with your current installation, or with Ubuntu, boot up with a live DVD/USB of Ubuntu. If the problem reproduces, it likely is a hardware defect because you ran that initial version previously without issues. If the problem does not reproduce in the live, the problem is likely with your current installation.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your input. I was able to boot it with a USB stick. However, the problem persists again when I attempt to run a software update, everytime I reboot after a software update, the display goes black and I cannot do anything.

Comment: So now, you already know more indeed.